# Android, EditText - How to "delinkify" already linkified (using Linkify class) text

Tags: android, hyperlink, android-edittext, linkify

Is there a way how to remove "linkification" that was done by `Linkify.addLinks(myEditText, Linkify.WEB_URLS);`?

It should be disabled by `Linkify.addLinks(myEditText, 0);`, but it doesn't affect the linkified text at all. Even using `myEditText.setLinksClickable(false);` has absolutely no effect (links are still clickable).

The only solution I have come up with is a little hacky:

> myEditText.setText(myEditText.getText().toString());

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It should be disabled by Linkify.addLinks(myEditText, 0);

Given that the method name begins with "add", I am not surprised that it leaves existing stuff intact.

> Is there a way how to remove "linkification" that was done by Linkify.addLinks(myEditText, Linkify.WEB_URLS);?

You can try to find and remove all `URLSpan` (or perhaps `ClickableSpan`) objects from the `Spannable`:

```
Spannable stuff=myEditText.getText();
URLSpan[] spans=stuff.getSpans(0, stuff.length(), URLSpan.class);

for (URLSpan span : spans) {
  stuff.removeSpan(span);
}

// *maybe* need myEditText.setText(stuff), not sure
```

Comment: Yes, this code works and "myEditText.setText(stuff)" is not necessary. Thanks!

Comment: @Tron: Ah, good. I wasn't sure if `getText()` returned the "live" object that was being edited or a copy, and if it was a copy, you'd need the `setText()` part. Glad it is working for you!